# Apache User change/create password on first login

Tags: php, apache, unix, .htpasswd

I have an index.php page for which i need to add user authentication

I have about 80 users that will need access to this page.

I want the users to change the password when they first connect to my page or a way for them to create their own password when they first connect with their username

is there a way to implement such a design ???

what will be the best way to do this as I don't wish to give all of them the same default password.

Comment: do you have their email addresses ?

Comment: yes i can get that if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if try to store user data in a database, this can be done by adding a flag (table field maybe named: force_new_pass) that if is true then show the user change password form

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using Apache's built-in `htpasswd` authentication, which is an extremely simple and inflexible login system.

You will need to write (or find somewhere open source) your own login system, probably backed by a database and PHP session storage.